# Interpreting the format specifier in printf("%# 01.1g",9.8)

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, language-lawyer, format-specifiers

Consider the following printf instruction:

```
printf("%# 01.1g", 9.8);
```

what should it print?

I'm reading the description of the **g** specifier on cppreference.com, which [says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) (text for `G` removed):

> converts floating-point number to decimal or decimal exponent notation depending on the value and the precision.
>
> For the **g** conversion style conversion with style **e** or **f** will be
> performed.
> Let P equal the precision if nonzero, 6 if the
> precision is not specified, or 1 if the precision is ​0​. Then, if a
> conversion with style **e** would have an exponent of X:
>
> - if P > X ≥ −4, the conversion is with style **f** and precision P − 1 − X.
> - otherwise, the conversion is with style **e** and precision P − 1.
>
> Unless alternative representation is requested the trailing zeros are
> removed, also the decimal point character is removed if no fractional
> part is left.

In our case,

- P = 1 , specified explicitly.
- X = 0, since a "conversion with style **e**", i.e. `"%# 01.1e"`, yields  `9.8e+00` (adjust the GodBolt program and you'll see).
- 1 > 0 >= -4  holds.

consequently, the conversion should be with style **f** and precision P - 1 - X = 1 - 1 - 0 = 0, i.e. `"%# 01.0f"`, which yields  `10.`.

... but that is *not* what glibc produces: I get  `1.e01`, as can also be seen on [<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/d5Yfv9e3a).

So,

- Am I mis-reading the quoted text?
- Is cppreference.com wrong?
- Is this - perish the tought - a glib 2.36 bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a lack of clarity about “a conversion with style `E`” and a discrepancy about what the precision means for `E` and `g`.

With `E`, the precision is the number of digits to appear after the decimal point, per C 2018 7.21.6.1 4. With `g`, the precision is the maximum number of significant digits. Those differ; `E` has an additional digit before the decimal point, giving a total of one more digit than its nominal “precision.”

Thus, in considering how to format 9.8 for `%.1g`, we first consider how it would be formatted for `%.0E`, not `%.1E`, as both `%.1g` and `%.0E` request one digit, whereas `%.1E` requests two digits. For `%.0E`, “1e+01” would be produced. So the *X*, the exponent, is 1, not 0.

Comment: Just to make sure - are you basing your answer on the text of the official standard, or are you interpreting how glibc behaves?

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike: Both. Think about the reason for “*P* > *X*”.  If *X* is as I described and *P* > *X* > 0, then we will produce *P* digits before the decimal point. But with the other interpretation, we sometimes have to produce *P* digits and a “0” before the decimal point, so *P* + 1 digits. That’s not the spirit of the `g` format; there should be exactly *P* digits (or fewer if we request trailing fractional zeros be removed)

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike: Also note what happens if the `e` format is selected, in the second bullet item from your quoted passage; the precision used is *P* − 1.  So the comparison of *P* > *X* is contemplating “What would happen if I printed this according to that second bullet item?” It is choosing betweem printing with `e` and precision *P* − 1 or with `f` and precision *P* − 1 − *X*, so the *X* that should be used is the one associated with that second bullet item.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [C standard (draft)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#page=287), precision means

> the maximum number of significant digits for the `g` and `G` conversions

In `"%# 01.1g"` the precision is 1 which means that the value will be rounded to one significant digit (9.8 is rounded to 10).

Now let's look at the definition of `g` from the same standard draft:

> A `double` argument representing a floating-point number is converted in
> style `f` or `e` (or in style `F` or `E` in the case of a `G` conversion specifier),
> depending on the value converted and the precision. Let *P* equal the
> precision if nonzero, 6 if the precision is omitted, or 1 if the precision is zero.
> Then, if a conversion with style `E` would have an exponent of *X*:
>
> - if *P* > *X* ≥ −4, the conversion is with style `f` (or `F`) and precision *P* − (*X* + 1).
> - otherwise, the conversion is with style `e` (or `E`) and precision *P* − 1.

In our case *P* = 1 (precision), *X* = 1 (exponent of 1e+01 which is 10 in exponential format)

*P* > *X* is false so the "otherwise" clause takes effect meaning that the exponential format should be used.

So both glibc and cppreference are correct and in fact the latter seems to be directly based on the standard.